# I am confused about this hot sauce nutrition label

Tags: nutrition, calories, labeling, macronutrient

So I know calorie rounding is a thing. Although I don't know how it really works. Something like if it's under 5 calories you can put it as zero, correct?

Regardless why is it, in the per 100 grams section, it says it contains 2 calories but 20 grams of carbs/sugar? How does that work?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per 100 gram:

- Sugars = 20 g x 4 kcal = 80 kcal
- Fiber = 2 g x 2 kcal = 4 kcal
- Protein = 1 g x 4 kcal = 4 kcal
- In total: 88 Kcal (368 kJ) and not 10kJ as stated.

Carbohydrate total is also wrong. It should be 22 g (not 20 g): 20 g of sugar and 2 g of fiber.

Comment: Did they invert the conversion from kcal to kJ?

Comment: Not that I would see that. It's completely off.

Comment: It is. What I meant was: "Q. – A: It does *not work*" – & your calc is much better than the label. Regardless of which country of origin (Thai here/above?) and different legislations. (Locally the labels say 25 total crabs/20 of that sugars – [compare](https://www.myfitnesspal.com/food/calories/huy-fong-foods-inc-sriracha-hot-chili-sauce-501395110)). My guess was, that they mixed up serving size & 100g, imperial measures/can sizes and the direction of conversions, plus rounding margins from local legislations and rounding errors dragged along the way. Exact relation unclear to me.

Comment: Ok so the label is wrong, cool. Man can't believe they'd mess that up, I swear it'd have to have some kind of screening process.